# filepicker.read() with options={base64encode:true} delivers unencoded data from CDN

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

I have a binary file picked/uploaded to cdn.filepicker.io/api/file/.
File is Excel (.xlsx, mimetype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet").

Next I'm trying to read the file, make some changes and write it back using filepicker v2. I'm using the code straight from filepicker v2 API documentation, and replaced blob with my uploaded file:

```
/* Blob from a previous pick */
var blob = {
    url: 'https://cdn.filepicker.io/api/file/<handle>',
    filename: 'spreadsheet.xlsx',
    mimetype: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    isWriteable: true,
    size: 72123
};

filepicker.read(
    blob,
    {base64encode: true},
    function(data){
        console.log("Read successful");
        // Here I'm processing data.
    },
    function(fperror) {
    //  console.log(FPError.toString()); - print errors to console
    }
);
```

### The Problem:

However, filepicker.read() call with options={base64encode:true} receives unencoded file - it returns the data (type is "string") to onSuccess() callback, which has most of the bytes as binary data in the original file. The unlucky bytes get jammed.

Inspecting file data in the browser debugger I see that for sure the data is not base64-encoded, and byte values above 0xA0 are replaced with utf8 bytecodes (more than one byte per the original byte).

Digging further, if I download the file in the browser using the link that filepicker_js client code prepares (e.g. https://cdn.filepicker.io/api/file/?base64encode=true&...), I get the original file, not base64-encoded.

Inspecting filepicker_js code, it uses xhr, but does not set any binary transfer options on it (e.g. responseType = "blob" or "arraybuffer", takes the data from responseText), which is a sure way to get utf8 conversion if the data comes in pure binary, unencoded. It can work with binary files ONLY if CDN base64-encodes them before sending.

To make it one step further, I made my own code to read the file from CDN, very similar to filepicker's read (even use the same composed URL), but in xhr implementation I set responseType="arraybuffer", received .response instead of .responseText, and the data arrived not corrupted anymore, proper binary. It matches the original file 100%.

BTW, The example code that displays an image on the documentation page https://www.filestack.com/docs/javascript-api/read/v2 seems working ok, and delivers base64-encoded data to the  element. I followed the call tree in the sources, and it uses FileReader for local files (not the CDN case!) and passes the data through fp.base64.encode().

### My conclusions:

1. filepicker CDN is broken, base64encode parameter is ignored.
2. Cannot use filepicker.read() on any binary file from filepicker CDN
3. Code inspection reveals that option "asText" might be needed. I tried it with and without, no difference for CDN reads - sending it to CDN via URL parameters does not change CDN behavior.

### Questions:

1. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or missed in the code posted above?
2. Is there any setting that should be checked (in the client or on developer portal)?
3. How can I get the CDN (base64encode=true) to be fixed?
4. What will it take to get filepicker_js sources and documentation to be fixed?

Comment: I believe this has been resolved by the filestack team.

Answer (score 0):

It does look like the response from the server is always assuming that the file is base64encoded and therefore is not encoding it because it thinks the file is has already been converted. I will make sure the Filestack Team remedies this. 
In addition, any questions or comments you have about the file uploads or documentation are always welcome at support@filestack.com

Comment: Were you able to contact the Filestack support team?